# How to capture group in question mark in regex?

Tags: c#, regex, sharepoint

I have this regex

`<SharePointWebControls:(\w+|_)+[=" _\w]*?(fieldname="(\w+|_)+")?[="' _\w<>%$:,]*?\/>`   with mode `gi`

and I'm testing it against

`<SharePointWebControls:FieldValue id="PageStylesField" FieldName="HeaderStyleDefinitions" runat="server" />`

And I want to capture two strings, `FieldValue` and `HeaderStyleDefinitions`. However the fieldname attribute may not exist, in which case just capture the first string, but if it exists, then capture both.

But in my regex, it always only captures the first string. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: -1 Please stop trying to invoke the wrath of Cthulu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using regex for XML comprehension. Use an XML parser instead.